# sending an error message from SQL to the browser

Tags: sql, error-handling, adodb, eof

I have a stored procedure for checking business rules in a holiday booking system but I need it to return error messages if it fails so far I have been using if statements and the else(my error is in the else) looks as follows:

```
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Error1'
    END
```

im using ASP adodb connection (apprentice in training) and this is how im trying to retrieve it:

```
     if not objDBRS.EOF then
        Session("Error") = objDBRS(0)
            if Session("Error") = "Error1" Then
                Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""you cannot book more than 10 days off"")</SCRIPT>")
            End If
end if
```

Currently it works correctly the stored procedure and doesn't do the code if it fails but the error is not returned to the browser for some reason so it doesn't hit the ASP if statement. so it works just doesn't get the client side JS message.

Comment: Long time since classic asp but shouldn't `objDBRS(0)` read `objDBRS.Fields(0)`.  That aside which line causes the error?

Comment: I'm not sure i have used `objDBRS(0)` in all my other methods of setting things from the database i used it and its fine, just this one that doesnt read.

Comment: Do you by any chance have `On Error Resume Next` before the open recordset?

Comment: no i don't, i don't understand what that even is. INB4 i am a noob and pretty new to coding

Comment: Can you show us the actual error you are getting? Include the line throwing the error if you can

Comment: Its not throwing any errors its just not returning an error anymore