# Is it possible to send any alert() message from sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to send any alert() message on browser page, direct from sql server ???

Comment: not as such as it is a javascript function

Comment: maybe you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345937/sending-an-error-message-from-sql-to-the-browser

Comment: Yes it is possible. By using `PRINT` command you can do this. this might be your desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOB and set alert to your email.